# Создание экземпляров одного класса внутри другого

Tags: python, python-3.x, классы

Не смог разобраться почему так происходит, изначальный код (упрощенная версия для наглядности):
Первый класс:

```
class Transaction:
   def __init__(self, amount, date, currency="USD",
             usd_conversion_rate=1, description=None):
    self.amount = amount
    self.date = date
    self.description = description
    self.currency = currency
    self.usd_conversion_rate = us_conversion_rate
```

И второй класс, в котором создаются экземпляры первого:

```
class Account(object):
    def __init__(self,check_number,check_name):
        self.check_number = check_number
        self.check_name = check_name
        self.transactions = []

    def apply(self, *args,**kwargs):
        new_transaction = Transaction(args,kwargs)
        self.transactions.append(new_transaction)

    def all_usd(self):
        print([x.currency for x in self.transactions if x.currency=='USD'])
```

Теперь запустим:

```
>>>a = Account(10,'jiff')
>>>a.apply(100,"2008-12-09","RUB")
>>>a.apply(10,"2008-12-09","EUR")
>>>a.apply(50,'234234','USD')
>>>print(a.all_usd())
['USD', 'USD', 'USD']
True
```

Как видно хотя были заданы три разные валюты, не смотря на это все три экземпляра класса создались с currency=='USD'.

Однако если поменять функцию apply вот так:

```
def apply(self, amount, date, currency="USD",
             usd_conversion_rate=1, description=None):
    new_transaction = Transaction(amount, date, currency,
             usd_conversion_rate, description)
    self.transactions.append(new_transaction)
```

Тогда все выводится корректно (только у одного экземпляра класса Transaction значение currency=="USD":

```
>>>a = Account(10,'jiff')
>>>a.apply(100,"2008-12-09","RUB")
>>>a.apply(10,"2008-12-09","EUR")
>>>a.apply(50,'234234','USD')
>>>print(a.all_usd())
['USD']
False
```

Не понимаю, почему так получилось (что неправильно в изначальной функции apply), поясните, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы передаете kwargs как обычный параметр вместо того, чтобы использовать его для аполнения параметров:

```
new_transaction = Transaction(args,kwargs) -> new_transaction = Transaction(*args, **kwargs)
```

По факту получается, что вы устанавливаете amount и date, а остальные значения берутся по умолчанию.

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался, правильно же понял, что у меня в коде получилось, что  в Transaction(args,kwargs) args и kwargs никак не ассоциировались питоном с *args и **kwargs и играли роль просто двух аргументов?

Comment: @Vova да, все так

Comment: Добавил бы, что вызывать нужно: `a.apply(10, "2008-12-09", currency="RUB")`, иначе "RUB" попадет в args, а не в kwargs.